# Run perl from golang

Tags: perl, go

I want to utilize perl from my golang application for regexp purposes. How can I run a perl file and communicate between the two processes? I have tried the package `os/exec` but it gave me a pointer as a final value.

Comment: I think the overhead of running perl through `os/exec` will outweigh any speed you may get through perl regex.

Comment: In this case I am not worried about speed. I just want to be able to use pcre

Comment: if you want to play around(not for production though) , there is also a package bradfitz/campher. DISCLAIMER: never used it myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think it to be not a good idea to use `os/exec` just to use regex. But if you absolutely need to.
Run it through `os/exec` command and then read it from `Cmd.Stdout` and `Cmd.Stderr`. For providing inputs you can use `Cmd.Stdin`.

You are getting pointer may be because you are not running the command. Is that how you are trying
 `c :=exec.Command('perl')`
Also run `c.Run()`

Comment: Can you provide an example for this please, I just do not know how to use Cmd.Stdout and Cmd.stderr. It is a good answer though. Thanks!

Comment: Re "*I do not think it to be not a good idea to use `os/exec` just to use regex.*", Definitely! Seeing as Go has [regex matching](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/).

Comment: @ikegami Theoretically there can be a reason, because Go lacks e. g. set operations on character classes, or `\X` (matches a grapheme).

Comment: If you are worried about matching `\X`, you will need to be extra careful that your input and perl code are encoded to UTF-8, and the perl code decodes both for the operation.

Comment: I just wanted to be able to do lookarounds

Comment: Also how do i send data into perl?

Comment: @tete Have a look at this [article](https://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/wOYk/advanced-command-execution-in-go-with-osexec.html).